# operator precedence of floor division and division

Tags: python, python-3.x, operators

I have trouble understanding why python returns different results for these 2 statements:

`-1 // 3/4`  and `-1 // 0.75`

The first one returns `-0.25` and the second on returns `-2`.

The way i understand it, the `/` operator is executed before `//` , thus those 2 statements should have the same result.

edit:
I was referring to a document provided by my university. I misinterpreted that. Official python documentation proves me wrong.
Thanks for all the quick answers.

Comment: What don't you understand from the Python documentation on the topic?  Please cite the source that gave you "The way I understand it".

Comment: I was referring to a document provided by my university. It says 'At the top are the operators with the highest priority' - in case you do not speak german. I think it is easy to see how i misinterpreted the document. [link to reference](https://moodle.studiumdigitale.uni-frankfurt.de/moodle3/pluginfile.php/56934/mod_resource/content/1/Programmierhandzettel%201.pdf) @Prune

Comment: Not at all easy :-)  : the document is not generally available.  Also, any source material should get edited into your question.  In any case, I think it's a moot point: several people have answered your question.

Comment: your provided link will not be accessible to anyone unless they are staff/student at your university.

Comment: I will do it right the next time. For now my question is answered. Thanks @Prune

Comment: That's the idea.  You also did right by up-voting useful posts and choosing an answer.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `/` and `//` operators have the same precedence according to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence) so they are evaluated from left to right when used in the same expression. `-1 // 3/4` is therefore equivalent to `(-1 // 3)/4` rather than `-1 // (3/4)`.

Answer (score 1):

> The way i understand it, the `/` operator is executed before `//` , thus those 2 statements should have the same result.

Your understanding is incorrect. `/` and `//` have the same precedence and have left associativity, meaning that Python performs the leftmost operation first - in your case, the `/`.

Answer (score 1):

The Expressions documentation has a section about [Operator Precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence). Operators in the same box have the same precedence.

Thus, the table tells you that `//` and `/` have equal precedence, so

`-1 // 3/4` parses as

```
>>> (-1//3)/4
>>> -0.25
```

Answer (score 1):

no, they have the same precedence, so they're evaluated from left to right.

`-1//3` is rounded (to the least integer) integer division, so you get `-1` divided by `4`: `0.25`

When you have doubts, it doesn't cost much to throw in a couple of parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

Think of these from an order of operations standpoint:

```
-1 // 3/4
```

This will perform `-1` "floor" `3`, which yields `-1`, which then divided by `4` yields `-0.25`.

Whereas:

```
-1 // 0.75
```

This will simply "floor" the operation straight away and yield `-2.0`.

Answer (score 1):

According to documentation, `Multiplication *`, `matrix multiplication @`, `division /`, `floor division //`, `remainder %` all have same precedence.

When two operators have the same precedence, associativity helps to determine the order of operations.

Now regarding your question; both `/` and `//` have same precedence, and if both of them are present in an expression, left one is evaluated first based on **left-to-right associativity**.

Answer (score 0):

// is essentially an operator for flooring division.

So 1 // 0.75 is essentially flooring 1.333 which is 1

-1 // 0.75 is essentially flooring -1.333 which is -2.

Hope this makes sense.